Excel - How to refresh mutiple pivot table in 1 sheet when the data source changes?
I have mutiple pivot table in 1 sheet, which are also linked to pivotcharts.
How can i have excel auto-fresh when i add columns / rows to my main data source?
I want to avoid changing the data source for each pivot table manually.
have tried using below VBA formular
But when i refresh, my pivot table still does not shows the newly added pivotchart fields.
How can i have the pivotchart field show on all pivotcharts?
VBA as below, is something wrong?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Only Refresh All Pivot Tables
For Each pc In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
pc.Refresh
Next pc

End Sub


If the data source of pvt is an Excel table (Insert > Table), refreshing pvt can catch the new data (in Excel table).

Do i need to convert my data to table? and how do i link multiples pivot table to the table ? want to avoid manually linking it.

You were close, but it's not PivotCaches it's PivotTables and I'm assuming there's pivot tables on more than one worksheet:
Sub RefreshAllPivotTables()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    ' Loop through each worksheet in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Loop through each pivot table in the worksheet
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
        Next pt
    Next ws
End Sub


Thanks Jeremy. All my pivot tables are under 1 worksheet. Does the above work as well?

If its for a single sheet only simply comment out the outer For Each ws & its Next ws. I tested it and it refreshes the Pivot Table, YMMV as I'm not sure how you're updating data but it works for me and you should test this code to get it working yourself.
